# How was this edit approved?

Tags: support, editing

[This edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61735) (and then [this edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61744)) is obviously bad: Another user has taken over the question, turning it into something completely different.

Yet it has been approved - by a user with 3 reputation.

How can that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until yesterday, the Gravatar icons for both the original Asker and the editor were the same, indicating they were unregistered accounts with the same email address.

Since the author of a post can cast a binding "accept" of any edits, they're obviously using multiple accounts to get around the warnings about poor contributions and now post bans.

Multiple of us have been swatting at this for the last few days.

Comment: fwiw WebApps does have post bans, and the person is now banned from asking http://i.imgur.com/NWHNsB6.png

Comment: Ah. That's new. Good.

Answer (score 7):

There is no bug. The author of a post can single-handedly approve or reject any edit to the post, regardless of their reputation.

Why would they approve it? Maybe they don't yet understand what the various buttons on this site do. Or maybe they are not really a different user.

The account of the editor has not produced anything worth keeping on the site, by the way.